# How to disable sqlite3 while using neoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I am using neoid with rails and want to disable sqlite in my rails application. How can I do this (after that I want to use only neoid and neo4j to store the data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

from your Gemfile and make sure that your config/database.yml file doesn't contain lines like

```
adapter: sqlite
```

Comment: I deleted gem record from Gemfile and deleted all records about adapters from database.yml. After that when I tried to perform "rake test" task I got:
    "rake aborted!
    test database is not configured"

Comment: So I deleted sqlite3 from my project but how can I add information about neoid to database.yml to force my tests to work. It seems that neoid doesn't provide mechanism for that.
@fabian

Answer (score -1):

From my testing with it today I don't think you can do this with this gem. Neoid adds neo4j storage as an addition to, not replacement for, your traditional RDBMS.

To have a full replacement for RDBMS-backed ActiveRecord you may need to consider the [neo4j.rb](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j) gem, which requires JRuby.